# Correlate two psychometric non-continuous variables

Tags: correlation

I would like to correlate two psychometric non-continuous variables, for example learning style (9 values) and results from a behavioral assessment (4 values).
What statistical test would be best to look at correlations between these two variables?
Are there similar studies for review?

Answer (score 0):

These variables sound like they are nominal (that is, they have no order). If that is true, the concept of correlation does not apply.  If you are asking about the *relationship* between the two, you can look at, e.g. crosstables and chi-square statistics. Or logistic regression. Or odds ratios. Or some other things.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback - crosstables and chi-squared statistics worked but wondered if you have a reference for using logistic regression in a similar case?

Comment: Any book on logistic regression.